# Disable and enable select buttons onClick of particular radiobutton

Tags: reactjs

I have one radio button group with three radio buttons and three select buttons.
Initially, all select button has to be disabled and once clicking on first radio button the first select button has to be enabled and the other two has to be disabled and same for 2nd and third also.how i can implement the above functionality?

Reactjs and Atlaskit packages

onRadioChange = (event)=> {
    console.log("radiobutton value triggred ", event.target.value)

```
if(event.target.value ==="user"){    
  console.log("click")
  this.setState({ 

    disabled_user : !this.state.disabled_user,
    disabled_schedule: this.state.disabled_schedule,
    disabled_team: this.state.disabled_team

  })

}
else if(event.target.value === "schedule"){
  this.setState("schedule")({            
    disabled_user : this.state.disabled_user,
    disabled_schedule: !this.state.disabled_schedule,
    disabled_team: this.state.disabled_team          
  })

}
else{   
    this.setState({ 
      disabled_user : this.state.disabled_user,
      disabled_schedule: this.state.disabled_schedule,
      disabled_team: !this.state.disabled_team      
      })

}

}

  <Select     
    id="user"             
    isDisabled={this.state.disabled_user}
  />
```

Comment: Please provide some code, so we can see what you've tried and correct you.

Comment: What code did you try?  Please add code with a question.

Comment: Ido , Sain Pradeep Thanks for response please go through the above code. I am a beginner in react.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is wrong. Don't switch the boolean values, set them explicitly. You also have an error in the second if. Do this:

```
if(event.target.value ==="user"){    
  console.log("click")
  this.setState({ 

    disabled_user : false,
    disabled_schedule: true,
    disabled_team: true

  })

}
else if(event.target.value === "schedule"){
  console.log("schedule")
  this.setState({            
    disabled_user : true,
    disabled_schedule: false,
    disabled_team: true          
  })

}
else{   
    console.log("team")
    this.setState({ 
      disabled_user : true,
      disabled_schedule: true,
      disabled_team: false      
      })

}
```

Comment: Thank you for answer its working. if i select first radio button particular select is enabling and i am getting data, while selecting second radio button  i want first select field has to be empty, here it is showing that  selected value. Please help me to find out this also

Comment: Well somewhere you forgot to add a condition to check if you should display data. Your original code is still incomplete, please post the rest of it, so I can help you

Comment: onRadioChange = (event)=> {
 if(event.target.value ==="user"){    
   this.setState({ disabled_user : false,
   disabled_schedule: true,
   disabled_team: true 
 }) }
 else if(event.target.value === "schedule"){
  this.setState({disabled_user : true,
  disabled_schedule: false,
  disabled_team: true }) }
   else { this.setState({ 
   disabled_user : true,
   disabled_schedule: true,
    disabled_team: false      
            })
      }}

Comment: <Select  
        id = "team"          
        className="multi-select"
        classNamePrefix="react-select"
        options={Team}
        isMulti
        isSearchable={false}                    
        isDisabled={this.state.disabled_team}
        styles = {customStyles}
       
       
      />
        
        <FieldRadioGroup
            items={Items}
            onRadioChange={this.onRadioChange}
        />

Comment: Nikola Diklic please give me solution

Comment: What is a "Select field"?

Comment: hi,I am using reactjs + atlaskit packages,this select field from atlaskit select field